tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\PycharmProjects\Emotion_Detection\output is not a directory
This is a sample Sentimental Analysis code for hotel reviews like positive or negative. I use pandas, transformers, datasets, turkish_lm_tuner libraries. Firstly, I think Path name (C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir so 'Ö' letter) and ı changed but it is not fixing and output give same error. Secondly,  I create  init.py in output folder but this way gives same error.  And I define path in enviromental variables but same errors is coming again.I search google and stackoverflow but ı can't find any way, I try many ways but I didn't. Please help me :) I search google and stackoverflow but I can't find any way, I try many ways but I'cant.Please help me :)
import os
import pandas as pd
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from datasets import Dataset
from turkish_lm_tuner import TrainerForClassification, EvaluatorForClassification

# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv('../Emotion_Detection/Hotel_readablee.csv')

# Define the output directory
output_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Ata Onur Özdemir\\PycharmProjects\\Emotion_Detection\\output'

# Check if the output directory exists
if os.path.exists(output_dir):
    # Check the contents of the directory
    print(f"Contents of {output_dir} directory:")
    print(os.listdir(output_dir))
    
    # Rename the directory
    new_output_dir = output_dir + "_old"
    os.rename(output_dir, new_output_dir)
    print(f"{output_dir} directory has been renamed to {new_output_dir}.")
    
    # Create a new output directory
    os.makedirs(output_dir)
    print(f"New {output_dir} directory created.")
else:
    # If the directory does not exist, create it
    os.makedirs(output_dir)
    print(f"{output_dir} directory created.")

# Initialize the tokenizer
model_name = "boun-tabi-LMG/TURNA"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Define the CustomDatasetProcessor class and other necessary steps
class CustomDatasetProcessor:
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, max_input_length):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_input_length = max_input_length

    def load_and_preprocess_data(self, data):
        dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(data)

        def preprocess_function(examples):
            # Convert each review text to string type
            positive_reviews = [str(review) for review in examples['Positive_Review_Tr']]
            negative_reviews = [str(review) for review in examples['Negative_Review_Tr']]

            # Use the tokenizer correctly
            tokenized_reviews = self.tokenizer(
                positive_reviews,
                negative_reviews,
                truncation=True,
                padding='max_length',
                max_length=self.max_input_length,
                return_tensors='pt'  # Return PyTorch tensors
            )

            return tokenized_reviews

        tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)
        return tokenized_dataset

# Initialize the dataset processor
dataset_processor = CustomDatasetProcessor(tokenizer, max_input_length=2048)

# Split the data into training, validation, and test sets
train_data = data.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=42)
remaining_data = data.drop(train_data.index)
validation_data = remaining_data.sample(frac=0.5, random_state=42)
test_data = remaining_data.drop(validation_data.index)

# Preprocess the datasets
train_dataset = dataset_processor.load_and_preprocess_data(train_data)
eval_dataset = dataset_processor.load_and_preprocess_data(validation_data)
test_dataset = dataset_processor.load_and_preprocess_data(test_data)

# Training parameters
training_params = {
    'num_train_epochs': 10,
    'per_device_train_batch_size': 4,
    'per_device_eval_batch_size': 4,
    'output_dir': output_dir,
    'evaluation_strategy': 'epoch',
    'save_strategy': 'epoch',
}

# Optimizer parameters
optimizer_params = {
    'optimizer_type': 'adafactor',
    'scheduler': False,
}

# Test parameters
test_params = {
    'per_device_eval_batch_size': 4,
    'output_dir': output_dir,
}

num_labels = 4  # Assuming you are performing binary classification

# Initialize TrainerForClassification
model_trainer = TrainerForClassification(
    model_name=model_name,
    num_labels=num_labels,
    task='classification',
    optimizer_params=optimizer_params,
    training_params=training_params,
    model_save_path="hotel_reviews_classification_model",
    test_params=test_params
)

# Train and evaluate the model
trainer, model = model_trainer.train_and_evaluate(train_dataset, eval_dataset, test_dataset)

# Save the trained model and tokenizer
model.save_pretrained("hotel_reviews_classification_model")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("hotel_reviews_classification_model")

# Evaluate the model using EvaluatorForClassification
evaluator = EvaluatorForClassification(
    model_save_path="hotel_reviews_classification_model",
    model_name=model_name,
    task='classification',
    test_params=test_params,
    num_labels=num_labels
)

# Evaluate the model on the test dataset
results = evaluator.evaluate_model(test_dataset)

# Convert the results to a DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)

# Save the results to a new CSV file
results_df.to_csv('evaluation_results.csv', index=False)
print("Evaluation results saved to evaluation_results.csv.")

# Check the current working directory
print("Current Working Directory:", os.getcwd())



System is given this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\PycharmProjects\Emotion_Detection\main.py", line 101, in <module>
    trainer, model = model_trainer.train_and_evaluate(train_dataset, eval_dataset, test_dataset)
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\turkish_lm_tuner\trainer.py", line 195, in train_and_evaluate
    trainer.train()
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 1885, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 2147, in _inner_training_loop
    self.control = self.callback_handler.on_train_begin(args, self.state, self.control)
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer_callback.py", line 454, in on_train_begin
    return self.call_event("on_train_begin", args, state, control)
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer_callback.py", line 498, in call_event
    result = getattr(callback, event)(
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\integrations\integration_utils.py", line 629, in on_train_begin
    self._init_summary_writer(args, log_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\integrations\integration_utils.py", line 615, in _init_summary_writer
    self.tb_writer = self._SummaryWriter(log_dir=log_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 249, in __init__
    self._get_file_writer()
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 281, in _get_file_writer
    self.file_writer = FileWriter(
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.event_writer = EventFileWriter(
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py", line 72, in __init__
    tf.io.gfile.makedirs(logdir)
  File "C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 513, in recursive_create_dir_v2
    _pywrap_file_io.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\PycharmProjects\Emotion_Detection\output is not a directory

D:\TEMP>tree PycharmProjects
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is A544-D3FB
D:\TEMP\PYCHARMPROJECTS
Invalid path - \TEMP\PYCHARMPROJECTS
No subfolders exist

What is unclear about ......PycharmProjects\Emotion_Detection\output is not a directory ??  It seems to mean that output is not a subdirectory of Emotion_Detection, or Emotion_Detection  is not a subdirectory of PycharmProjects.

@Luuk  I controlled all path and all of them is valid directory. Code is create folder but it doesn't read own folder, I can't give any meaning this error, I have been searching solution 3 -4 days.

I’m voting to close this question because the problem is not reproducible

@Luuk yes but I need solution, because its my Internship project and ı must be solving this problem that's why I can't close the question.

Try to share the TREE info (at the bottom of my answer on the directory C:\Users\Ata Onur Özdemir\PycharmProjects, and use [edit] to add that info to your question.  (and check if this Folder is accessible via File Explorer)

@Luuk I write the our commands and gives too long output. You want to last part or all of them

@Luuk I added last part

so output is not a directory..... It is probably a file?

@Luuk yes output is a file but code is create this folder, I don't know difference between directory nd  file, I knew both of them same. What can ı do for solution?

Check the contents, and decide if it is valuable. If uncertain you can always rename it. After renaming you should be able to create the directory output.

@Luuk I tried your solution but output is same, ı updated code in question. If you think wrong my steps please give me feedback. Code is created output folder but folder is null and it has not any valuable. What can i do for valuable?

I did not mean you to change code. Only move the file output to output.bak, and then check your (original) code for it's working.

@Luuk  I tried your solution truthly but output is same

I created a Minimal Reproducible Example of this problem:
import os

output_dir = 'D:\\TEMP\\PhycharmProjects\\Emotion_Detection\\output'

if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)
    print(f"{output_dir} created!")
elif not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
    print(f"{output_dir} NOT created!")
    raise NotADirectoryError(f"{output_dir} is not a directory")

running this code gives following output:
D:\TEMP>python testdir.py
D:\TEMP\PhycharmProjects\Emotion_Detection\output created!

I even double checked (which is not needed but.... )
D:\TEMP>tree PhycharmProjects
Folder PATH listing for volume HDD
Volume serial number is D46B-804B
D:\TEMP\PHYCHARMPROJECTS
└───Emotion_Detection
    └───output


I'm trying again solution for you and output is like yours but error is same. Thanks for advice.
